# Adding another JOIN to query and getting table column titles

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

I am working on a data to CSV function but I'm stuck.

So far it's getting all data from two tables and putting onto a CSV file all in 1 line for each order with invoice data and customer data .

I need to also get invoice_items by ID as well (those I guess will need to be looped as might have more than 1 item but unsure how to add invoice_items to the query and also I need to set the titles as well for the columns but unsure how).

It would be awesome if it could be like this:

> |invoice details customer details | invoice items
>
> ```
>                                LIST ITEM
>
>                                LIST ITEM
>
>                                LIST ITEM
> ```

rather than

> invoice details | customer details | invoice items LIST ITEM LIST ITEM
>   LIST ITEM

with real data and titles would look something like

> id | invoice number | amount | name | address | invoice items (and
>   list below this part)

PHP

```
header("Content-type: text/csv"); 

    // output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('.$mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $file_name = 'invoice-export-'.date('d-m-Y').'.csv';   // file name
    $file_path = 'downloads/'.$file_name; // file path

    $file = fopen($file_path, "w"); // open a file in write mode
    chmod($file_path, 0777);    // set the file permission

    $query_table_columns_data = "SELECT * 
                                    FROM invoices i
                                    JOIN customers c
                                    ON c.invoice = i.invoice
                                    WHERE i.invoice = c.invoice
                                    ORDER BY i.invoice";

    if ($result_column_data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_table_columns_data)) {

        // fetch table fields data
        while ($column_data = $result_column_data->fetch_row()) {
            $table_column_data = array();
            foreach($column_data as $data) {
                $table_column_data[] = $data;
            }

            // Format array as CSV and write to file pointer
            fputcsv($file, $table_column_data, ",", '"');
        }

    }
```

Comment: can't you loop trough $table_column_data and use the fputcsv in the loop, so each invoice would be on the next line?

Comment: I have the going onto the next line already, i think im going to not export items as cannot see me working that out but am trying to work out how to set the column title names - any ideas?

Comment: I tried // fetch titles
     while ($headers = mysqli_fetch_field($result_column_data)) {
     foreach($headers as $header) {
       $head[] = $header->name;
   }
  }

Comment: Hi James. An substantial answer below from Kickstart, which would have taken quite some time to write up, remains conspicuously unreplied to, after more than two years. They have my upvote now, but if you have abandoned this question, would you at least give them the tick mark? You are clearly still signing in. It's worth remembering that sites like Stack Overflow operate on the basis of goodwill as well as gamification.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to join to another table to get the invoice items.

I also suspect that your current example query is joining the tables incorrectly, as you appear to be joining the customers and invoices tables based on the invoice. As I expect a customer could have many invoices, but an invoice only has one customer I would expect the invoice table to store the relevant customer id, and then do a join based on that.

As such you could get the details with something like this:-

```
SELECT i.id,
    i.invoice_number,
    i.amount,
    c.name,
    c.address,
    ii.invoice_item
FROM invoices i
INNER JOIN customers c
ON c.id = i.customer_id
INNER JOIN invoice_items ii
ON ii.invoice_id = i.id
ORDER BY i.invoice
```

Note I have switched from SELECT * to selecting the column names (which I am guessing at), as SELECT * is frowned upon for various reasons. You could alias the column names if you wanted something more readable.

But you want a list of titles taken from the column names. Assuming you do not want to just hardcode these I would suggest that you switch from using mysqli_fetch_row to mysqli_fetch_assoc, which will return the column names.

You can then process the column names on the first row and output those. Something like this:-

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/csv"); 

    // output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('.$mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $file_name = 'invoice-export-'.date('d-m-Y').'.csv';   // file name
    $file_path = 'downloads/'.$file_name; // file path

    $file = fopen($file_path, "w"); // open a file in write mode
    chmod($file_path, 0777);    // set the file permission

    $query_table_columns_data = "SELECT i.id,
                                    i.invoice_number,
                                    i.amount,
                                    c.name,
                                    c.address,
                                    ii.invoice_item
                                FROM invoices i
                                INNER JOIN customers c
                                ON c.id = i.customer_id
                                INNER JOIN invoice_items ii
                                ON ii.invoice_id = i.id
                                ORDER BY i.invoice";

    if ($result_column_data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_table_columns_data)) 
    {
        // fetch table fields data
        if ($column_data = $result_column_data->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $table_column_head = array();
            $table_column_data = array();
            foreach($column_data as $field_name->$data) 
            {
                $table_column_head[] = $field_name;
                $table_column_data[] = $data;
            }
            // Format array as CSV and write to file pointer
            fputcsv($file, $table_column_head, ",", '"');
            fputcsv($file, $table_column_data, ",", '"');
            while ($column_data = $result_column_data->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                $table_column_data = array();
                foreach($column_data as $data) 
                {
                    $table_column_data[] = $data;
                }
                // Format array as CSV and write to file pointer
                fputcsv($file, $table_column_data, ",", '"');
            }
        }
    }
```

Expanding that a bit to only put out the invoice details on the first row for an invoice

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/csv"); 

    // output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('.$mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $file_name = 'invoice-export-'.date('d-m-Y').'.csv';   // file name
    $file_path = 'downloads/'.$file_name; // file path

    $file = fopen($file_path, "w"); // open a file in write mode
    chmod($file_path, 0777);    // set the file permission

    $query_table_columns_data = "SELECT i.id,
                                    i.invoice_number,
                                    i.amount,
                                    c.name,
                                    c.address,
                                    ii.invoice_item
                                FROM invoices i
                                INNER JOIN customers c
                                ON c.id = i.customer_id
                                INNER JOIN invoice_items ii
                                ON ii.invoice_id = i.id
                                ORDER BY i.invoice";

    if ($result_column_data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_table_columns_data)) 
    {
        // fetch table fields data
        if ($column_data = $result_column_data->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $table_column_head = array();
            $table_column_data = array();
            foreach($column_data as $field_name->$data) 
            {
                $table_column_head[] = $field_name;
                $table_column_data[] = $data;
            }
            $prev_id = $column_data['id'];
            $prev_invoice_number = $column_data['invoice_number'];
            $prev_amount = $column_data['amount'];
            $prev_name = $column_data['name'];
            $prev_address = $column_data['address'];

            // Format array as CSV and write to file pointer
            fputcsv($file, $table_column_head, ",", '"');
            fputcsv($file, $table_column_data, ",", '"');
            while ($column_data = $result_column_data->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                if ($prev_id == $column_data['id'] AND $prev_invoice_number == $column_data['invoice_number'] AND $prev_amount == $column_data['amount'] AND $prev_name == $column_data['name'] AND $prev_address == $column_data['address'])
                {
                    $different_invoice = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $different_invoice = false;
                    $prev_id = $column_data['id'];
                    $prev_invoice_number = $column_data['invoice_number'];
                    $prev_amount = $column_data['amount'];
                    $prev_name = $column_data['name'];
                    $prev_address = $column_data['address'];
                }
                $table_column_data = array();
                foreach($column_data as $field_name->$data) 
                {
                    $table_column_data[] = (($different_invoice or $field_name == 'invoice_item') ? $data : '');
                }
                // Format array as CSV and write to file pointer
                fputcsv($file, $table_column_data, ",", '"');
            }
        }
    }
```